# AHK + Subtitles app = 100% hands-off subtitles fetching?

Tags: automation, autohotkey, subtitle

I'm new here so bear with me if I'm asking in the wrong place. I recently came across a very simple subtitle downloader for Windows and Mac called Subtitles (http://subtitlesapp.com/). It makes downloading subtitles dead simple but I was thinking of a neat way to streamline the process even more.

First, some context:

Normally what I would do is download a TV show or movie, then go to subscene.com (or any subtitles site) and look for the appropriate subtitle file for my video. What subtitles does is make the process easier. It takes a video file as input (drag onto the UI or open with the program) and it instantly searches for an appropriate subtitle file. Once it finds something it downloads the subtitle with the same name as the original video file and in the same folder, all with no interaction from the user besides opening the video file.

What I want to do is this:

Is it possible to have AutoHotKey monitor a folder, so when video files are added to it, they are automatically run through Subtitles in the background and thus the appropriate subtitle is fetched? The result would be: download Movie / TV show to special folder and boom subtitle is already there. I want to go from *almost* no interaction with Subtitles app to absolutely no interaction with Subtitles + AHK.

Is something like this possible with AHK?

-- **Update**

Well, following [MCL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963690/ahk-subtitles-app-100-hands-off-subtitles-fetching#comment29716608_19963690) advice and going through the forums it seems what I'm looking for can be done with a function called [WatchDirectory](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/60125-ahk-lv2-watchdirectory-report-directory-changes/), I just haven't figured out all of it yet. Basically what I want to do is watch the Downloads folder for .mkv, .avi, and .mp4 files and whenever a movie file is added, open it with a program called Subtitles. I don't want it to do anything when the file is moved out of the directory, its name is changed, etc. And I don't want any reports of the changes or anything like that. Simply when the file is added run it through the Subtitles app.

With a variant of code posted on the WatchDirectory thread I somewhat got it working but it's still rather unpredictable. It sometimes launches, or it launches multiple instances, or it launches whenever I move the file out of Downloads instead of when it is copied to downloads. This is my first script so I'm still struggling to wrap my head around this function and how AHK works. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
#persistent
SetTimer, loop, 100
WatchDirectory ("C:\Users\jvilc_000\Downloads*|.mkv|.avi|.mp4","OpenFileWith")
return

loop:
if (Exit)
   SetTimer, Loop, Off
return
#g::Exit := true

OpenFileWith(from, to)
{
   Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Subtitles\Contents\Windows\Subtitles.exe %from%
}
```

Comment: May be better place for this question in [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. And by the vagueness of your question I deduce you haven't tried to find that out yourself. A google search for *autohotkey monitor folder* yields [WatchDirectory()](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/41653-watchdirectory/). Searching for *autohotkey http request* leads to [HTTPRequest()](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/67989-func-httprequest-for-web-apis-ahk-b-ahk-lunicodex64/). Please do some of this research on your own and try to get something started. As soon as you have an actual coding question, people will be glad to help you out.

Comment: Tried to get something started and it sort of works, but very buggy still. Added some new information to original post.